# angular16: operate data before return it

Tags: angular, httpclient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpJwa.jpg)
angular16 httpclient

How could I format the data before returning it? This has been confusing me.

I tried to use "subscribe" "map" but it did not working.

Or am I doing wrong? what should I do if I want to put the data that from a server into a component?

I expect a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `pipe(map(...))`, not to subscribe.